# Pandas findall re.IGNORECASE doesn't work

Tags: python, pandas, findall, keyword-search, ignore-case

I have a list of keywords:

```
keywords = ['fake', 'hoax', 'misleading', etc.]
```

I'd like to search the `text` column of DataFrame `df1` for the above keywords and return rows containing these keywords (exact match), both in uppercase and lowercase (case-insensitive).

I tried the following:

```
df2 = df1[df1.text.apply(lambda x: any(i for i in re.findall('\w+', x, flags=re.IGNORECASE) if i in keywords))] 
df2
```

The above code returns all rows with the specified keywords, BUT it doesn't include the uppercase words (e.g., it return text containing "hoax", but not "HOAX").

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex here is working properly, but not really doing anything of note. `'\w+'` will match any "word" character (regardless of case) that occurs one or more times in sequence. This will match individual, space-separated words, as I presume you intended.

The problem lies in your `if i in keywords`. As an example, if `re` comes across the word `"FakE"`, it will correctly be included in the result of `re.findall`, but then your code will check if `"FakE"` is in `keywords`, which it is not (for membership checks, case *does* matter). Changing the final part of your lambda function to `if i.lower() in keywords` should resolve this issue.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried you code, but it doesn't return the uppercase words (e.g., HAOX). Also, it returns fewer rows compared to `re.findall` that I used before.

Comment: I changed `if i in keywords` to `if i.lower() in keywords` and it worked. As you mentioned, the problem was `if i in keywords`. Thanks for the hint :) I voted up your response, but didn't accept it as answer because it didn't return the correct results for me.

Comment: Hm, okay. I've removed the last part about using `x.split()` instead of `re.findall`. I added it mostly as an afterthought anyway.